# (PHP) Login doesnt work

Tags: php, authentication

Today I made a code that should do a login but sadly it wont.

here is what I tried:

```
include('php/mysqlcon.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=$username AND password=$password");
    $query_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($query_rows > 0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        echo('bad login');
    }
}
```

The mysql details are in the mysqlcon.php, and Im sure they are correct

Comment: You need to escape your SQL statements too. Otherwise you'll provide a terribly open target for SQL-injection attacks. Look at PDO or others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your username and password in the query. Also, make sure you filter the input since your code is prone to mysql injection.

Comment: what do you mean with filtering?

Comment: You need to escape the POST values since users can send malicious codes that way that can really make a mess. See [here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php), but there are tons of other resources as well. And for escaping, this function is great: [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you did it. But please remember to ALWAYS FILTER THE INPUT (I can't stress this enough). Here's another resource: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=20438 . Also, it would be great if you switched to another MySQL extension, like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to wrap your `$username` and `$password` in quotes when creating your mysql query, currently you'll end up with a faulty query on most cases.

You should also google "How to prevent sql-injection php" when you're at it, currently you are prone to this type of attack (which can lead to serious trouble).

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement und put the credentials into parameters for the SQL Query.

Comment: The classic mysql_-functions do not have prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

`"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"`